# Внешние ключи при миграциях symfony3

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

Как добавить внешний ключ при миграциях?
Используется DoctrineMigrationsBundle

Есть таблица house :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И таблица user:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+код миграции

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{

    $houseTable = $schema->getTable('house');

    $table = $schema->createTable('user');
    $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', ['autoincrement' => true, 'unsigned' => true]);
    $table->setPrimaryKey(['id']);
    $table->addColumn('first_name', 'string', ['length' => 255]);
    $table->addColumn('last_name', 'string', ['length' => 255]);
    $table->addColumn('password', 'string', ['length' => 255]);
    $table->addColumn('slat', 'string', ['length' => 255]);
    $table->addColumn('email', 'string', ['length' => 255]);
    $table->addColumn('created', 'datetime');
    $table->addColumn('updated', 'datetime');
}
```

Мне нужно организовать связь один ко многим (у пользователя много housов).
Как это сделать?

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу: а какой инструмент используется для описания миграций?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev DoctrineMigrationsBundle

Comment: Добавил в описание

Comment: Я обычно в ентити делаю связь потом мигрэйшн дифф и миграция сама готова

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich а можно в генерации entity делать связи?
Имею ввиду, когда с консоли это делаешь

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не хочу писать связи руками

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich а зачем делать тогда миграции, если таблицы можно сгенерить с entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$houseTable->addForeignKeyConstraint($table, array('user_id'), array('id'));
```